# Reader - Writer mutexes

Tags: c, mutex

This is the reader-writer problem for just read consistency.
Here is the algorithm:

```
void reader() {
    while (1) {
        P(mutex); 
        rc++;
        if (rc == 1) P(db); /* <---- A */
        V(mutex); /* <---- B */
        read_data_base();
        P(mutex);
        rc--; 
        V(mutex);
        if (rc == 0) V(db);
    }
}

void writer() {
    while (1) {
        P(db); 
        write_data_base();
        V(db);
    }
}
```

Here are my questions:
1. What is the purpose of line A in the reader code?
2. If we eliminate that line will the code still work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The purpose of line A, is to check if the current reader is the first one after a write (or the first one overall). If this is the case, then he has to obtain the database mutex (db), so that no writer can write to the database, while there is at least one reader reading it.

  The corresponding line for the last reader is:

  `if (rc == 0) V(db);`

  The purpose of this line, is to check if the current reader is the last reader, so that a writer can enter next (if there isn't another reader that enters before the writer).
- Based on the above description, if you eliminate line A, your code won't work correctly.

**Note**: As seen in Vlad's answer below (and the discussion in the comments thereof), `V(mutex)` should be after `if (rc == 0) V(db)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the code is wrong: you need to execute `if (rc ==0) V(db)` under locked `mutex`.

The line A is needed in order to lock the database for reading. Lock is set at the first reading operation, and released after the last one; as well it's set during each of the possible writing operations. If the lock won't be set, the read and write operation could be executed simultaneously, which results in corrupt data.

Comment: Are you sure that the code is wrong? Can you tell an example, where an error would occur?

Comment: i also think it's wrong..

thread 1:
// assume rc == 0
V(mutex);

switch to thread 2:
P(mutex); 
rc++; // now rc == 1

switch to thread 1:
if (rc ==0) V(db); // rc is already 1 so it forgets to V(db).

Comment: Of course. Imagine that a reader #1 comes in thread #1, and executes till the line `if (rc ==0) V(db);` (but not including it). Now context switches to thread #2. In the thread #2 comes another reader, locks the mutex, increments `rc`, now the value of `rc` is 2. Therefore the second reader doesn't lock `db`. Now context switches to thread #3, in this thread a writer tries to lock the db, obtains the lock, and modifies the data which are currently being read by the thread #2. So the data will be corrupted.

Comment: @Vlad: Although I'm two years late with this comment, if reader #1 reaches the line you say, it will have already decreased `rc`, therefore its value will be 0 before reader #2 enters and 1 after that.

Comment: @3lectrologos: Okay, more fine-tuning :) (1) `rc == 0` (2) reader in thread 1 executes until `if (rc ==0)`, now `db` is locked and `mutex` is not locked. (3) reader in thread 2 executes till `if (rc == 1)`, now `rc == 1`, `db` is still locked (by the reader in thread 1) and `mutex` locked as well. (4) reader in thread 1 executes `if (rc ==0) V(db)`. As `rc != 0`, this does nothing. (5) reader in thread 2 continues by `if (rc == 1) P(db)`. This waits forever as the `db` is already locked.

Comment: @3lectrologos: furthermore, no other reader will unlock the `db`, since `rc` will be always at least 1 at reader iteration start.

Comment: @Vlad: Yes, I agree. `V(mutex)` should be after `if (rc == 0) V(db)`. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @3lectrologos: you're welcome! Thank you for the fruitful discussion (I had to rewrite my comment several times until I got the needed example).

Answer (score 0):

The writer should not write while anybody is reading. Therefore any reader blocks db while he reads, if he is the early bird (#1). And he has to clean up the blockade if he is the last guy in the room (rc == 0) as well.